# Earth revolve Around the sun.

Tags: earth-rotation

Why earth revolve around the sun in oval axis. Why not in round axis? If the gravitational force of the sun is same at every place .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And [it is already answered there](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8288/what-is-the-orbit-of-earth-around-the-sun), so don't post the question there again.